# Find the Laplace transform f(s) for the figure showing below

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

[Figure](https://i.imgur.com/7DBkZWd.jpg)

I tried to solve it and came up with this [solution](https://i.imgur.com/MIhhyI6.png).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @copper.hat what do you mean? I already posted a link to it. Here it is again: http://m.imgur.com/7DBkZWd?r

Comment: @Abdulrahman You can simplify the expression, otherwise your solution is fine

Comment: @Bubububu Thanks! I just wanted to make sure it's correct before preceding further. It looks painful simplifying that question lol.

Comment: One way is to notice that $f(t) = 2u(t)-u(t-1)-u(t-2)$ and then you get $\hat{f}(s) = {1 \over s} (2 -e^{-s}-e^{-2s})$. Your answer is correct but needlessly complicated.

Comment: You should use MathJax when posting questions. Posting phone pics. is frowned upon or, more typically, gets fewer views. To see how equations are written, right click on an expression and select Show Math As->Tex Commands.

Answer (score 0):

The unit step function can have many interpretations depending on what sources your looking at.

$$f(t)=\begin{cases} 2,  & \text{if $t$ t: [0,1]} \\ 1, & \text{if $t$ t: [1,2]}
\end{cases}$$

for $t\in [0,1]$,
$F(s)=\int_0^\infty 2e^{-st} dt = \frac{s}2$. After taking the inverse Laplace $\implies$ $f(t)=2$

for $t\in [1,2]$
$F(s_1)=\int_0^\infty 1e^{-s_1t_1} dt = \frac{s_1}1$ where $t_1=t-1$. After inverse Laplace $\implies$ $f=f(t_1)=1$

Since $t_1=t-1$ you can substitute $t(t_1)=t_1+1$ into f which becomes $f=1$.